# How to use switch case in JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I am trying to display normal message using JSON switch case. I have written code also code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = '{ "R000092201": "EIN and Name should be same","F229000501":"Your Form is Incomplete, Please add the Credit Vehicle Details (Contact Support for any further queries)","F229002201":"Your Form is Rejected, Please ensure you select either EFW or EFTPS Payment (Contact Support for any further queries)"}';

    var obj = JSON.parse(text);
    var clients = '<%= clients%>';
    alert(clients);
    switch (clients) {
        case 'R0000-922-01': document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.R000092201;

        case 'F2290-005-01': document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.F229000501;

        case 'F2290-022-01': document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.F229002201;
    }
</script>
```

In above code based on backend data i.e **<%= clients%>** corresponding case should execute, but in my code it is not **For example**  clients value whatever always 3rd case message is displaying. Where I have been going wrong please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `break;` after each case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = '{ "R000092201": "EIN and Name should be same","F229000501":"Your Form is Incomplete, Please add the Credit Vehicle Details (Contact Support for any further queries)","F229002201":"Your Form is Rejected, Please ensure you select either EFW or EFTPS Payment (Contact Support for any further queries)"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var clients = '<%= clients%>';
alert(clients);
switch (clients) {
    case 'R0000-922-01': document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.R000092201;
    break;
    case 'F2290-005-01': document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.F229000501;
    break;
    case 'F2290-022-01': document.getElementById('lblrejectionmsg').innerHTML = obj.F229002201;
    break;
}
```

if you miss the break; always all the case after matching case will execute. so add break; after each case block.

Comment: `break;` is optional. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Though the `break;` is optional,  According to the question asked, the `break;` is needed to break the execution

Comment: Pugazh break is optional in terms of your program semantic, but if you want to run only one  case block, the break is required.